# can i integrate ovi map in my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ovi

I want to use the [Nokia Ovi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovi_%28Nokia%29) map in my iPhone application. Is it possible? If so, please help me to find a link to some API documentation and steps for integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokia Ovi Maps run on any HTML5 compatible browser, thus you can embed it in your application with UIWebView (see the documentation of this class on how to do it). According to Nokia you can do the followings:

- You can see where you are on the map, thanks to HTML5 support for
  positioning
- You can find addresses, businesses and other places of interest, anywhere in the world
- You can get to know the places: all the essential information about a place are presented on one page (pictures, user reviews, popular travel guides description, contact information)
- You can plan the fastest route to your destination by car or on foot
- You can see where the public transport lines go, and where the stops are
- You can share your favourite places with your friends via SMS, email, Facebook or Twitter

Found here: http://blog.maps.nokia.com/archive/nokia-maps-goes-to-ios-and-android